# Selenium webscraper not scraping desired tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

here are the two tags I am trying to scrape: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1sVN.png. In case you are wondering, this is the link to that page (the tags I am trying to scrape are not behind the paywall): https://www.wsj.com/articles/chinese-health-official-raises-covid-alarm-ahead-of-lunar-new-year-holiday-11672664635

Below is the code in python I am using, does anyone know why the tags are not properly being stored in paragraphs?

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://www.wsj.com/articles/chinese-health-official-raises-covid-alarm-ahead-of-lunar-new-year-holiday-11672664635'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

paragraphs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'css-xbvutc-Paragraph e3t0jlg0')

print(len(paragraphs)) # => prints 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two problems impacting you.

1. you should wait for the page to load after you get() the webpage. You can do this with something like `import time` and `time.sleep(10)`
2. The elements that you are trying to scrape, the class tags that you are searching for change on every page load. However, the fact that it is a `data-type='paragraph'` stays constant, therefore you are able to do:

```
paragraphs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@data-type="paragraph"]') # search by XPath to find the elements with that data attribute

print(len(paragraphs))
```

prints: `2` after the page is loaded.

Comment: Wow this worked, thank you so much! Although I don't understand what you mean when you say the class tags change every page load. I have been trying to scrape this tag by the class name for the past couple days and the class name has always been 'css-xbvutc-Paragraph e3t0jlg0'

Comment: @GauravVarma After a second look it seems like you are correct. The alternative way instead of by XPath would be by class name such as `find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'css-xbvutc-Paragraph')` As class attributes are those that are separated by a space (in this case there are multiple classes that the element is apart of) CLASS_NAME does not select by both classes which is why you had a problem prior.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add-on to @Andrew Ryan's answer, you can use [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for shorter and more dynamical waiting time.

```
paragraphs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@data-type="paragraph"]'))
)
print(len(paragraphs))
```